# Error was using Javascript in apple script function

Tags: javascript, applescript

Im getting a syntax error "Expected “,” but found identifier." And im not quite sure why?

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell document 1 to set failedTest to (do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('specDetail failed')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].title;")
end tell
```

From here its highlights JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome doesn't have a "do Javascript" command. Try "execute javascript" .